# Xcode Succeeds Build, but does not copy to iOS Device, and terminates debugger immediately

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

This problem is pretty ridiculous and I'm running out of ideas of what to try:

I have been successfully using Xcode to debug my game on my iOS device (iPhone) for the past couple of weeks, but now all it will do when I try to do a run with my iPhone set as target is successfully build the application and then Stop immediately. No Errors, nothing in console logs.  The application doesn't even copy over to my device.

Xcode says: Building, Running, Finished Running....all within 2 seconds...

I'm using Xcode 4
iOS 4.3

I've tried the following:

1. Rebooting mac
2. Deleting application from iPhone and
   rebooting iPhone (although my power
   button no longer works on my iPhone,
   so I had to run down the entire
   battery to try this)
3. Cleaned project and rebuilt

Nothing seems to help.
The game compiles and runs successfully on the iOS Simulator within Xcode as well, and as I've said I've been able to copy my game over prior to yesterday, but for some reason it just stopped working...

UPDATE: Solved by setting the "accelerometer" from "NO" to "YES" in Info.plist.

Comment: Does anything in this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364434/xcode-fails-to-deploy-iphone-app-to-iphone-3gs

Comment: No, I've tried reinstalling my provisioning profile as well...same result :(

Comment: Is the device jailbroken? I've had lots of issues with my jailbroken test device and Xcode w/ Live Debugging on-device.

Comment: No it's not jailbroken.  I found out what the issue was, and I can't believe it...In my Info.plist, I changed Required Device Capabilities of "accelerometer" from "NO" to "YES" ....unreal.

Comment: Ooops, but just as a side point, if you're not using source control or snapshots might be a good thing to get that up and running. You'd have been able to spot this mistake a lot quicker and avoided the frustration by doing a few diffs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by setting the "accelerometer" from "NO" to "YES" in Info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

I know you found your answer but I found a similar case when starting a project from XCode 4, the app plist contains a required device capabilities "armv7".
So even after adding armv6 to the build settings, the program didn't run on a 3G.
I deleted the required device capabilities "armv7" and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, the problem for me was a blank value in my plist under "Required Device Capabilities." Deleting the blank value fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was "gps" value in plist under "Required Device Capabilities." 
Deleting it fixed the issue for iPad2.